# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/common/type/WriteCloneable jogl 2 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception, jogl

I am on windows 7 64 bit and using eclipse indigo. I downloaded the latest version of jogl 2 and i have created an eclipse project following this link

https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-2

this tutorial is old as the jars in the jogl download dont match and i have included all the jars and for each jar set the native libraries directory. I have written a small jogl test program that creates a GLProfile, GlCapabilities and an awt frame. I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/common/type/WriteCloneable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 24 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

seems like im missing a jar..could any let me know what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using the jogl-all.jar from Matlab 2014a. The error above disappeared and everything run smoothly when I added the library **glugen-rt.jar**.

(remember also to -Djava.library.path=/path/to/native/files when you execute your application, in my case this was -Djava.library.path=/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64)

Answer (score 6):

Try to add gluegen as well.

For example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc11</version>
</dependency>
```

AND

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the JOGL jar files. See [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/JAR-inquisition-td3277996.html). Also, check out the tutorials on the [jogamp wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial) (by the looks of it Wade is pretty active on the wiki).