# JOGL errors on compilation

Tags: java

I am working with JOGL and it stopped working completely.

These are the errors i get:

```
Texture01.java:27: error: cannot access WriteCloneable
    canvas = new GLCanvas(glcapabilities);
             ^
class file for com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable not found
.\Texture01_GLEventListener.java:2: error: package com.jogamp.common.nio does not exist
import com.jogamp.common.nio.*;
^
.\Texture01_GLEventListener.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
    FloatBuffer fb = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable Buffers
  location: class Texture01_GLEventListener
.\Texture01_GLEventListener.java:163: error: cannot find symbol
    IntBuffer ib = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(indices);
               ^
  symbol:   variable Buffers
  location: class Texture01_GLEventListener
4 errors
```

The Path and Classpath variables are correct, I reinstalled JDK and JOGL2 but still get an error with WriteClonable and com.jogamp.common.nio.*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576691/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-jogamp-common-type-writecloneable-jogl-2-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/common/type/WriteCloneable jogl 2 in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576691/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-jogamp-common-type-writecloneable-jogl-2-in)

Comment: Nope, not usign matlab and the files i used are from the latest build